# Where can I find the simple information of the format for uploading questions?

Tags: retrieve-and-rank, watson

**Situation:**

I want to train and simple configure the retrieve and rank service.
I just uploaded some PDFs and now I want to upload some questions.
In the documentation I do not find a simple information how the csv file must be structured and which are the must fields and which are not must files.

Something like: *"[YOUR QUESTION (MUST)]"*,*[DOCUMENT ID (MUST)]*, *[RANKING (OPTIONAL)]*

The document ID you will find in *xyz* in section *xyz*.

Inside the help I can not find such kind of help.

https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/retrieve-rank/training_data.shtml#script

**Impact:**

There is no chance to get a "real" documentation of the configuration outside the tutorial.

**Possible Solution:**

Provide additional documenation.

Maybe I was not able to find it and someone can guide me to the right place?

Comment: Are you referring to uploading questions in the Retrieve and Rank tool? e.g. this screen https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWfJ2.png

Comment: @dalelane Thanks for your comment and you rightn the picture shows request for upload, but if you also take a look in the help it has confused me. Also, it does not contain a real “data format advice”. To avoid misleading simple persons like me, it would be cool to have a more detailed and in sync documentation or sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution for me, by try and error. Following steps do work for me:

1) You need a plain text file and the ending should be *.txt

2) Inside the file you have to write your questions like this:

```
   What is the best place to be?
   Why should I travel to the USA?
```

-> Don't do it like

```
   "What is the best place to be?"
```

For me the help was missleading, because saying something about CSV files.
You can take a look also in the comment of @dalelane he is right, and highlight the entry text for the upload of the file.